# Embedded chat on website not loading css correctly

Tags: css, einstein, embedded, bot

After made some changes to Einstein bot apex files and published in production some strange things happen on our production website embedded chat so basically did not change anything that was related to chat UI. Only the backend logic in apex classes. And what's important that on one website on staging env it works perfectly. How ever on production after changes it got broken. And I notice that there is an error "Refused to get usafe headers "Server-Timing". but it also appears in staging env too. but everything works fine. In addition to this the production website is wordpress based and I'm testing it on MVC5 .Net framework.
What I have tried:

- undo my all my changes.
- create new bot from scratch.
- check that all css is loaded from sf but its greyed out.

Wondering if its from salesforce side or not?